# Select next div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
//$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.next').click(function(){
  $('.box').fadeOut();
  $('.box').next().fadeIn();
 });
//});
```

```css
.box{
 border:solid 1px #ccc;
 padding: 20px;
 width:10%;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="next" style="cursor:pointer;">next</a> <br><br>
<div class="box" style="display:block;">
 1
</div>

<div class="box">
 2
</div>

<div class="box">
 3
</div>

<div class="box">
 4
</div>
```

I have a div `.box`, and the next button. I need to select the next div if i click the `next` button but only the first div not all. For example if i click `next` button while it shown `box 1` then the next box that should be appear is `2` and so on. But  now it shown `2 3 4`. How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the first visible div using `$(.box:visible)` and then fadeIn next div to it. you can also add a check for last element, in which case you can fadeIn the first element. something like this:

```js
//$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.next').click(function(){
        var visibleBox = $('.box:visible');
  $(visibleBox).fadeOut();
  if(!$(visibleBox).next('div').length)
           $('.box').first().fadeIn();
        else
           $(visibleBox).next().fadeIn();
           
 });
//});
```

```css
.box{
 border:solid 1px #ccc;
 padding: 20px;
 width:10%;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="next" style="cursor:pointer;">next</a> <br><br>
<div class="box" style="display:block;">
 1
</div>

<div class="box">
 2
</div>

<div class="box">
 3
</div>

<div class="box">
 4
</div>
```

Comment: i want 3rd box after 2nd box, and 4th box after 3rd box. How to do it sir ?

Answer (score 2):

It's showing `2 3 4` because you ares selecting **ALL** `.box` elements, i.e. `1 2 3 4`

`.next()` of `1` = `2`

`.next()` of `2` = `3`

`.next()` of `3` = `4`

`.next()` of `4` = nothing

You should find the box that is currently being shown, and then find it's next sibling.

```
// Filter by CSS rule
var $showing = $('.box').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') === 'block';
}).fadeOut();

// or using :visible
$showing = $('.box:visible').fadeOut();

$showing.next().fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use another class to labeled, which div is on the display. for example, you add a class `display`. then you put that class, on the first box. when you click next, you can remove the class display from the current one, and move it into the next one.

HTML

```
<a class="next" style="cursor:pointer;">next</a> <br><br>
<div class="box display">
    1
</div>

<div class="box">
    2
</div>

<div class="box">
    3
</div>

<div class="box">
    4
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    width:10%;
    display:none;
}
.display{
  display:block
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    var current = $('.box.display');

current.fadeOut().removeClass('display').next().fadeIn().addClass('display');
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/dfaLnsmo/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement this will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 1;
    $('.next').click(function(){
        $('.box').fadeOut();
        $('.box:nth-child(i)').fadeIn();
        if(i >= $('.box').length)
        i++;
        else
        i=1; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Jquery

```
var curr = 1;
$('.next').click(function(){
  if(curr < $( ".box" ).length) {
    $('.box').hide();
    $( ".box" )[curr].style.display= "block";
    curr += 1; 
  }
});
```

Here is the working jsfiddel : https://jsfiddle.net/Lv7yr820/1/